# form_for with datetime_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime-select

I am using Rails 3.1 and first time using `datetime_select`. I want to specify the minute select box to have 15 minute intervals rather than 1 minute intervals:

```
  <%= f.datetime_select :start_datetime, :ampm => true, :start_minute => [0,15,30,45] %>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The `:start_datetime` is what the property is called in the `Event` model. Is it possible that this is a reserved word that is causing problems?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try passing :minute_step => 15

```
<%= f.datetime_select :start_datetime, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 15 %>
```